# Is there any way to use sigqueue on OS X?

Tags: linux, macos, signals, sigqueue

I 've recently noticed that sigqueue doesn't work on OS X (mac OS Sierra), i 'd like to know if there is way without using a virtual machine (linux)

Comment: From what I've read by googling, it looks like it's generally not available on Unix versions based on BSD rather than System V or Linux.

Comment: See the portability note [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/manual/html_node/sigqueue.html)